# How to use remote-redux-devtools with NgRx?

Tags: angular, redux, nativescript, ngrx, remote-debugging

I have been using NgRx in an Angular NativeScript (Android & iOS apps) project and it really is working well. The only thing that kind bothers me is that I can't use `@ngrx/store-devtools` and the `Redux DevTools` Chrome extension because the apps run on a mobile device or emulator. I know that `react-native` can connect to remote dev tools so there must be a way if NgRx can work with remote dev tools.

I see that there is a package for such a situation `remote-redux-devtools` [(link)](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools) but I'm a little lost on how to connect that to NgRx. I understand about setting up a local `remotedev-server` [(link)](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remotedev-server)  so the `Remote DevTools` from the Chrome extension can connect to that, **but I'm not sure how to connect NgRx in my project to the `remotedev-server`.**

Here is an example of the main Angular module where NgRx is setup. With a regular redux project, the remote tools are connected where the store is initialized. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this NgRx? Thank you!

```js
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';

import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from '@nativescript/angular';

import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EntityDataModule, EntityDataService } from '@ngrx/data';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';

import { PROVIDERS } from './services';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    NativeScriptFormsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),  // With regular Redux the remote-devtools would go here.
    EffectsModule.forRoot(),
    EntityDataModule.forRoot(entityConfig),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({  // Can remote-devtools be connected here somehow?
      maxAge: 25,
      logOnly: environment.production,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    ...PROVIDERS,
  ],
// ...
```

### **EDIT 1/26/2020**

Just to mention the [article](https://medium.com/nextfaze/remote-debugging-ngrx-store-with-ionic-74e367316193) that @devakone posted about the `iconic` framework because I had also found it and it's almost exactly what I need except one part. It's where he uses the `window` object to tie the remote dev tools extension and Angular together. There is no `window` object in NativeScript but I'm sure there is a way to access the `devToolsExtension` or `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__` in a similar way.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RemoteDevToolsProxy } from './remote-devtools-proxy';
// ...

// Register our remote devtools if we're on-device and not in a browser
if (!window['devToolsExtension'] && !window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__']) {
  let remoteDevToolsProxy = new RemoteDevToolsProxy({
    connectTimeout: 300000, // extend for pauses during debugging
    ackTimeout: 120000, // extend for pauses during debugging
    secure: false // dev only
  });

  // support both the legacy and new keys, for now
  window['devToolsExtension'] = remoteDevToolsProxy;
  window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__'] = remoteDevToolsProxy;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyApp],
  // ...
  StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(),
  // ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**So it really boils down to, how can I do:**

```js
window['devToolsExtension'] = remoteDevToolsProxy;
window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__'] = remoteDevToolsProxy;
```

**in NativeScript considering NativeScript does not have a `window` object? Where could I access `devToolsExtension` or `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__`?  Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

I have a demo repo showing how to do this with Nativescript 7(NS7) and NG11. I believe it should be possible to rig this to work with Nativescript  8 with NG 12 using this same methodology.

https://linuxsimba.github.io/ns7-ng11-ngrx-remotedevtools